# D3 with custom element: TypeError: t is null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use D3 v.4 with a canvas element (following the pattern introduced [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/d3-and-canvas-in-3-steps-8505c8b27444)). I want to bind my data to a custom element, so that it is accessible in memory but isn't rendered to the page like an svg. However, the code below throws: `TypeError: t is null`. I can't get a good stack trace on the error.

```
const data = [{a:1,b:2},{a:2,b:4}]; 

const dataContainer = document.createElement('custom');
const container = d3.select(dataContainer)
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('custom')
      .attr('class','element')
      .attr('test-data-attribute', (d) => { return d; });

const nodes = container.selectAll('.element');
console.log(nodes.length);
```

Codepen demo here: https://codepen.io/jaredsk/pen/OgPMpL?editors=0010 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're trying to do (which I'm not really following), for that enter selection to work you have to use `selectAll`:

```
const data = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    a: 2,
    b: 4
}];

const dataContainer = document.createElement('custom');
const container = d3.select(dataContainer)
    .selectAll(null)// <---- selectAll here
    .data(data).enter()
    .append('custom')
    .attr('class', 'element')
    .attr('test-data-attribute', (d) => {
        return d;
    });

const nodes = container.selectAll('.element');
console.log(nodes);
```

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRbPjb?editors=0110

PS: I removed the `length` in `console.log(nodes.length)` because, in D3 v4.x, selections are **objects**, not arrays anymore.